# .eslintrc.js for React 17 and JSX without import 'react'

Tags: reactjs, eslint

in react 17 is not necessarily use

```
import React from 'react';
```

but if i don't have it, so eslint gave me error

```
'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope
```

any idea how modify .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
    ],
  plugins: [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "jsx-a11y",
  ],
  rules: {
    strict: 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

for react 17?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can read about it in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#eslint).

> If you are using `eslint-plugin-react`, the `react/jsx-uses-react` and `react/react-in-jsx-scope` rules are no longer necessary and can be turned off or removed.

```
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
  }
}
```

- [`react-in-jsx-scope` on github](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md).

To make it work, you should add those rules to your `eslint` config, see [Extending or replacing the default ESLint config](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config) for Create-React-App specifics, every framework should have related section in their docs.

Comment: where exactly do we need to add these rules?

Comment: Add it to your eslint config, depending on your framework, see updated answer

Answer (score 23):

You need to add `plugin:react/jsx-runtime` to `extends` in the `.eslintrc.js` file.

like is:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
  ]
}
```

Maybe a warning: `Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .`

You need to set like this

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
  ],
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
}
```

[Refer here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/577cb64fb6/README.md#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing challenges and all these solutions did not work. This worked for me.

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```