# Prettier / ESLint / React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier

Conflicting rules on TS / React import from a noob, but using Eslint / Prettier and getting an `'React' is declared but its value is never read.` error, but if i remove it, `'React' must be in scope when using JSX` error pops up. I can't work out why!

```
ReactDOM.render(<Hello greeting="Site under construction..." />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
import React from 'react';

export interface IProps {
    greeting: string;
}

function Hello({ greeting }: IProps) {
    return <div>{greeting}</div>;
}

export default Hello;
```

> /Users/Jeremyrrsmith/Coding/GitHub/portfolio-site/src/components/Hello.tsx
> TypeScript error in /Users/Jeremyrrsmith/Coding/GitHub/portfolio-site/src/components/Hello.tsx(undefined,undefined):
> 'React' is declared but its value is never read.  TS6133

But if I remove the import from Hello.tsx above

> src/components/Hello.tsx
> Line 6:12:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Try this `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: Make sure you are using React version 17+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646593/11561000 this solved it for me, thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last react version of react doesn t need the import. Use that one or fix your eslint which is the problem here