# Eslint 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, eslint

When I run `yarn eslint .` I got this result:

```
  5:10  error  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

[image]

The problem is that in this file, I dont need to import React, because the IDE showing:

```
'React' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
```

[image]

So what do I do to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 2):

React in new version doesn't need to import React when writing JSX, and to fix eslint, this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646593/11410031